# Install the package from the specific channel with conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I need the version 5.12 of the `qt` package in anaconda, but version 5.9.7 is installed.

```
>>> conda list qt -f
# packages in environment at /PATH/anaconda3/env/my_env
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1
```

Since the latest version of `qt` in the default channel `anaconda` is 5.9.7(https://anaconda.org/anaconda/qt), I want to install `qt` package from the channel `conda-forge`, which has the version 5.12.5(https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qt).

So I tried to install `qt` from `conda-forge` channel with this command.

```
>>> conda install qt -c conda-forge --override-channels
```

But conda didn't install `qt` from the new channel and printed that all packages are already installed.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

FYI, my channel configuration in .condarc is

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
channel_priority: disabled
```

Why does not conda update `qt` and how to install `qt` from the channel `conda-forge`?

Comment: You can prefix packages with a channel: `conda install conda-forge::qt` - you can also force installing a specific version by `conda install "qt>=5.12"`

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `.condarc` file is mis-specified if you want `conda-forge` to take priority.  You want this:

   ```yaml
   channels:
     - conda-forge
     - defaults
   channel_priority: flexible  # or 'strict'
   ```
2. If you want a specific version, try specifying the version in your command.  You can even both version and specific build id:

   ```sh
   # This effectively means qt 5.12.*
   conda install -c conda-forge qt=5.12

   # You can also specify the exact version and build ID, if you happen to know them:
   conda install -c conda-forge qt=5.12.5=hd8c4c69_1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a dependency problem on `qt` from `conda-forge`.

I could get `qt` from `conda-forge` by upgrading all packages from `conda-forge`.

```
conda upgrade -c conda-forge --all
```